# Отследить нажатия play по видео с ютуба в iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет, ни как не могу реализовать такую задумку. На странице есть несколько видео роликов. Они выводятся с базы данных. Вот кусок `iframe` кода как я их вывожу

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yxjo4MHTLNU?enablejsapi=1"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Помогите отловить воспроизведения ролика, что бы когда ролик запустили выводилось сообщение, например Привет мир. Реализовать это все чудо хочу на `JavaScript` ну или на `JQuery` Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взято отсюда и модифицировано, [ссыль](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619074/play-iframe-video-on-click-a-link-javascript):

На codepen пример работает http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNVYVZ 
Здесь не пашет видимо, потому что скрипт вставляется не в html-примера, а html страницы данного сайта stackoverflow.

Конкретно вас интересует именно функция onPlayerStateChange(event) - правил ее.

Ссылка на документацию https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=ru

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}


function onPlayerReady(event) {
  //event.target.playVideo();
  document.getElementById('play').innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="play();">Play Video</a>';
}

function play() {
  player.playVideo();
}


var done = false;

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    alert('играет');

  }
}

function stopVideo() {
  player.stopVideo();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="player"></div>
  <div id="play"></div>
</body>

</html>
```